# When I open IAR Embedded (ARM) project it auto close and I can not see what happen, I can not find any solve, also I wrote IAR team but no answer

Tags: c, embedded, iot, iar

my project include SPI & UART communitation and I can open it another pc, I try reinstall and also reinstall old version but no solve. 
without code I can't post question and I have not problem with code.

Comment: Try a [command line build](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/general/build-from-the-command-line/) - it may work, or it may give you a more useful error report.  If it works, then it is an EWB issue not an issue with the project file or the tool chain.

Comment: Also, try delete all output files and generated files first (manually), then open IAR as administrator and see if problem persists.